# Decimal Format Saying "String cannot be converted to double"

Tags: java, decimalformat

I'm trying to round the volume of a sphere to 1 decimal place, but I keep getting an error saying String cannot be converted to double. So then instead of trying to format a variable, I just put a number to try and find the issue and it still said that a string can't be converted to double. What am I doing wrong and how do I get it to format my variable to one decimal place?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double diameter;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");



        //User Input Section
        while (true) {
        System.out.print("What is the diameter of the sphere (cm): ");
        try {
            diameter = input.nextDouble();
        break;  
        } catch (InputMismatchException mme) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number in number format (e.x. 1, 55, 6)");
            input.nextDouble();
        }
        }
        
        double radius = diameter/2;
        double radiusCubed = radius * radius * radius;
        double radiusSquared = radius * radius;
        double fourOverThree = 4/3;

        double volumeOfSphere = fourOverThree * Math.PI * radiusCubed;
        double volumeOfSphere2 = df.format(1.1111111);
        double surfaceAreaOfSphere = 4 * Math.PI * radiusSquared;



        System.out.print("The volume of the sphere is " + volumeOfSphere2);
    

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DecimalFormat.format` returns a `String`. But you are assigning it to a `double` variable.

Change the statement as:

```java
String volumeOfSphere2 = df.format(1.1111111);
```

*While receiving such errors, please read the javadoc available for the method and check if the return type/parameter type are matching with what you have specified.*

Answer (score 0):

**DecimalFormat.format()** method return a string. You can **parse** it to double by passing it through **Double.parseDouble()** method.

```
double volumeOfSphere2 = Double.parseDouble(df.format(1.1111111));
```